# Cannot be resolved error in JavaEE project

Tags: java, mysql

I am doing this for a semestral project. I just opened my JavaEE file and had this issue, it was fine on Friday which was the last time I opened it but as you can see my DBAO shows it has none. Everything says cannot be resolved. This file was meant to connect to MySQL database.

[image]

Comment: Try Project->Clean->Clean all projects.

Comment: i never do that before, do i need to do a backup before i clean?

Comment: @RealSkeptic it didn't work

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I see. Sorry for that. Since its my first time using stack overflow . I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

1. restart Eclipse
2. Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects followed by Project -> Build All
3. right click on the error project -> properties -> java build path -> check any build path missing, it looked like your JRE is missing, try selecting the right or existing JRE

Comment: oh yes, it is my JRE issue, i see that my version now is 1.8.0_131, and my recent java updated version is 1.8.0_141, is there a way to change my JRE version for the project? Sorry still a newbie here

Comment: if you are in the build path screen, and select the JRE, on the right side there should be an "Edit" button, click on that, and see if you can find any available JRE in the next screen, otherwise click the "Installed JREs" button which will bring up the search for JRE screen where you can search for your installed JRE and use it

Comment: Yay thanks for your help, it worked. And sorry for the late response.